# Google Cloud Datastore: Counting all entities in a certain state

Tags: python, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-functions

**Background**

I need to send out a large batch of notifications to around ~1 mil devices and I'm building it out using Google Cloud Functions.

In the current setup I enqueue each device token as a PubSub message that:

- stores a pending notification in DataStore, used for keeping track of retries and success status
- attempts to send the notification
- marks the notification as either successful or failed if it's retried enough and hasn't gone through

This works more or less fine and I get decent performance out of this, something 1.5K tokens processed per second.

**Issue**

I want to keep track of the current progress of the whole job. Given that I know how many notifications I'm expecting to process I want to do be able to report something like x/1_000_000 processed and then consider it done when the sum of failures + successes is as much as what I wanted to process.

The DataStore documentation suggests not running a count on the entities themselves because it won't be performant, which I can confirm. I implemented a counter following their example documentation of a [sharded counter](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/sharding_counters) which I'm including at the end.

The issue I'm seeing is that it is both quite slow and very prone to returning `409 Contention error`s which makes my function invocations retry which is not ideal given that the count itself is not essential to the process and there's only a limited retry budget per notification. In practice the thing that fails the most is incrementing the counter which happens at the end of the process which would increase load on notification reads to check their status on retry and means that I end up with a counter that is less than the actual successful notifications.

I ran a quick benchmark using wrk and seem to get around 400 RPS out of incrementing the counter with an average latency of 250ms. This is quite slow comparing to the notification logic itself that does around 3 DataStore queries per notification and is presumably more complex than incrementing a counter. When added to the contention errors I end up with an implementation that I don't consider stable. I understand that Datastore usually auto-scales with continuous heavy usage but the pattern of using this service is very rare and for the whole batch of tokens so there would not be any previous traffic to scale this up.

**Questions**

- Is there something I'm missing about the counter implementation that could be improved to make it less slow?
- Is there a different approach I should consider to get what I want?

**Code**

The code that interacts with datastore

```py
DATASTORE_READ_BATCH_SIZE = 100

class Counter():
    kind = "counter"
    shards = 2000

    @staticmethod
    def _key(namespace, shard):
        return hashlib.sha1(":".join([str(namespace), str(shard)]).encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()

    @staticmethod
    def count(namespace):
        keys = []
        total = 0
        for shard in range(Counter.shards):
            if len(keys) == DATASTORE_READ_BATCH_SIZE:
                counters = client.get_multi(keys)
                total = total + sum([int(c["count"]) for c in counters])
                keys = []
            keys.append(client.key(Counter.kind, Counter._key(namespace, shard)))

        if len(keys) != 0:
            counters = client.get_multi(keys)
            total = total + sum([int(c["count"]) for c in counters])

        return total

    @staticmethod
    def increment(namespace):
        key = client.key(Counter.kind, Counter._key(namespace, random.randint(0, Counter.shards - 1)))
        with client.transaction():
            entity = client.get(key)
            if entity is None:
                entity = datastore.Entity(key=key)
                entity.update({
                    "count": 0,
                })
            entity.update({
                "count": entity["count"] + 1,
            })
            client.put(entity)
```

This is called from a Google Cloud Function like so

```py
from flask import abort, jsonify, make_response
from src.notify import FCM, APNS
from src.lib.datastore import Counter

def counter(request):
    args = request.args

    if args.get("platform"):
        Counter.increment(args["platform"])
        return

    return jsonify({
        FCM: Counter.count(FCM),
        APNS: Counter.count(APNS)
    })
```

This is used both for incrementing and reading the counts and is split by platform for iOS and Android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I gave up on the counter and started also saving the status of the notifications in BigQuery. The pricing is still reasonable as it’s still per use and the streaming version of data inserting seems to be fast enough that it doesn’t cause me any issues in practice.

With this I can use a simple sql query to count all the entities matching a batched job. This ends up taking something around 3 seconds for all the entities which, compared to the alternative is acceptable performance for me given that this is only for internal use.